# Find antiderivative of $ln(x)^y$ for any real y

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

What is this antiderivative? I have tested several values of $y$ in an online antiderivative calculator, but it's not clear how they are related. Here $y$ is fixed and I want the antiderivative with respect to $x$. I am particularly interested in the value of the integral with respect to $x$ over $(0, 1)$, for values of $y$ for which $ln(x)^y$ is defined there.

Comment: No, with respect to $x$ please.

Comment: For $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\ln x<0$, so $(\ln x)^y$ is not even defined for arbitrary real $y$.

Comment: @AlexM. “For any real $y$” is clear enough.

Comment: Yes, thank you Alex.

Comment: I did not mean $y$ in $[0, 1]$, by the way: I mean integrate with respect to $x$ over $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

We set:

$$\text{I}_y=\int\ln^y(x)\space\text{d}x$$

Now, by integration by parts:

$$\text{I}_y=x\log^y(x)-y\int\log^{y-1}(x)\space\text{d}x=x\log^y(x)-y\cdot\text{I}_{y-1}$$

So, by induction we can find that:

- When $y=0$:
  $$\text{I}_0=x+\text{C}$$
- When $y\ge1$: 
  $$\text{I}_y=x\ln^y(x)-y\cdot\text{I}_{y-1}$$

---

Mathematica gives:

$$\text{I}_y=\frac{\ln^y(x)\Gamma\left(1+y,-\ln(x)\right)}{\left(-\ln(x)\right)^y}+\text{C}$$

Where $\Gamma(a,x)$ is the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: This only works for $y \in \Bbb N$. The OP asked for $y \in \Bbb R$ (the OP explicitly mentions $y \in  [0,1]$). I believe that for $y \notin \Bbb N$ the problem does not have a solution expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Sure, I've checked it with Mathematica and there is only a 'nice' closed form when $y\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: It's easy to see why the integral can exist only for integer $y$.

Comment: @egreg Mathematica gives $\int \sqrt{\ln(x)} dx = x \sqrt{\ln(x)}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfi}(\sqrt{\ln(x)})$ so no, the integral can exist for non-integer $y$.

Comment: @Jacob Only when $x>1$, of course, but the OP seems to be interested in $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @AlexM. if I am not mistaken, you'll eventually need to integrate something like $\int_0^1\ln(x)^{\delta<1}$, so your solution at least cannot be a real one, maybe this is what egreg meant - still, it can exist